# Select only duplicates from inner joined table

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates, inner-join

So I am very new to sql and need some help. I have an inner joined code of 3 tables:

```
SELECT *
FROM Activity 
Inner UserActivity on UserActivity.activity_id = Activity.activity_id 
Inner Join User on UserActivity.user_id = User.user_id 
;
```

From this code it creates a mega table, which is great. But now I want to select only the duplicate entries for 6 columns, activity_name, activity_time, user_id, email, first_name, and last name. I would like to group these by activity_time.

These specific columns look like:

```
activity_name  activity_time   user_id   email           first_name   last_name
Reading        00:00:15        10001     btv@gmail.com   Mike         Porter
Share          00:01:10        10765     ud@gmail.com    Jamie        Hollands
Like           23:15:00        15761     rsv@gmail.com   Ragav        Taylor
Tweet          07:59:01        17001     trv@gmail.com   Julie        Smith
```

How can I do this?

Thank you!

Comment: Please show sample input and output, it's not clear what you want here.

Comment: Show us sample data and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: You have to show us three things, what you have, what you want and what logic use to go there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a COUNT, GROUP, HAVING combination to filter duplicate rows.

```
SELECT  activity_name, activity_time, user_id, email, first_name, last name, COUNT(*)
FROM Activity 
INNER JOIN UserActivity on UserActivity.activity_id = Activity.activity_id 
INNER JOIN User on UserActivity.user_id = User.user_id 
GROUP BY activity_name, activity_time, user_id, email, first_name, last name
HAVING COUNT(*)>1
```

Comment: you need `group by`